# How to specify variables in tensorflow simple save

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying unsuccessfully to save my tensorflow model using the simple save method.

I have built a model using keras and trained it successfully, with an accuracy of 88%.  I am now trying to save this model so we can serve it, but the function I need, simple save, isn't clear about how to specify the variables that get passed in.

The the session and the export directory is clear enough, but the inputs and outputs are mysterious.  I believe that because I've used Keras, these variables are hidden by the abstraction of keras and the documentation from Tensorflow on simple save offers no explanation.

As a hailmary, I set Z equal to y just to put something in there, but obviously that is wrong.  Do I need to set up an output variable Z, and if so, what type is it?

Not sure if this is enough code to get to the bottom of this.  Even getting pointed at the right docs would be a big boost.

```
import tensorflow as tf
session =  tf.keras.backend.get_session()
export_dir = "/Users/somedir/"
z = np.array([])
tf.saved_model.simple_save(session,
            export_dir,
            inputs={"x": X, "y": y},
            outputs={"z": z})
```

X is my dataset -- an array of all independent variables.  Y is the outcome (dependent variable). I don't have another candidate for z, so I set it to an empty array.

I get AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that **you can query the model itself** for its inputs and outputs.

Don't forget to import the right libs:

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.python.saved_model
```

Then set an export path variable, for convenience this is timestamped, so you can run this again and again:

```
export_path = "/somedirectory/{}".format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))
```

Then inside of get_session() block, the following will do the trick:

```
with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        export_path,
        inputs={t.name:t for t in model.inputs},
        outputs={t.name:t for t in model.outputs})
```